# how to reload the UIImage in myView in iphone

Tags: iphone

i have created an app which is used to select an image in an DetailViewclass and the selected picture willbe added to anotherViewClass. i got the picture in another view which was selected in the DetailViewclass. but  i want UIImage to be empty when the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

set the image of uiimageview to nil in the viewwillapear and again allocate it the image in viewwillappear.

in viewwillappear

```
imageview.image=nil;
imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:mynewimagename];
```

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 0):

How about using putting a code setting UIImageView instance's image to nil in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?